# Pivotal quantity inference statistics of Exponential distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, exponential-distribution, pivot

Bus waiting times are distributed like this (they are independent)

[image: independent]

I know the average time  is 8 minutes.
I need to find the pivotal quantity of Theta parameter and after it of P. (P is the probability that waiting time will take more than 5 minutes )

I don't know How to treat each of them separately ? (P and $\theta$) ?

Answer (score 1):

If $T_1, T_2, \dots, T_n$ are exponentially distributed with mean $\theta,$
then one can show (e.g., using moment generating functions( that
the sample mean $\bar T$ has
$\frac{\bar T}{\theta} \sim \mathsf{Gamma}(\mathrm{shape}=n, \mathrm{rate}=n).$

Then one can find values $L$ and $U$ that cut probability $0.025,$
respectively, from the lower and upper tails of $\mathsf{Gamma}(n,n):$

$$0.95 = P\left(L \le \frac{\bar T}{\theta} \le U\right)
= P\left(\frac{\bar T}{U} \le \theta \le \frac{\bar T}{L}\right),$$
so that a 95% confidence interval for $\theta$ is of the form
$\left(\frac{\bar T}{U},\;\frac{\bar T}{L}\right).$

Here is an example in R with thirty observations from an exponential distribution with rate $\lambda = 1/8$ and mean $\theta = 8.$

The resulting 95% CI is $(5.52, 11.35),$ which does cover the
population mean $8,$ as should happen for 95% of such datasets.
[In R, probability functions for exponential distribution use the
rate $\lambda = 1/\theta$ as the parameter.]

```
set.seed(101)
t = rexp(30, 1/8)   # data: 30 0bservations
summary(t)

   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0.373   2.631   4.737   7.660  10.455  30.051 

ci = mean(t)/qgamma(c(.975,.025), 30, 30);  ci 
[1]  5.517638 11.353423
```

Finally, $P(T_i > 5) = e^{-5/\theta} = e^{-5/8} = 0.5353.$

```
1 - pexp(5, 1/8)
[1] 0.5352614
```

Then the CI for the probability is $(0.4040, 0.6438).$

```
exp(-5/ci)
[1] 0.4040628 0.6437815
```

*Note:* If you are not familiar with gamma distributions or computations in R,
then you can look at information on the gamma and chi-squared distributions
(perhaps in your text or the relevant Wikipedia pages) to see how to use printed tables of the chi-squared distribution to
get the 95% CI for $\theta.$

Comment: I can't use R, and I know Gamma. I need to use Pivotal Quantities, and to get an numeric answer for theta and for P. but I dont succeed undertsand in which Pivotal Quantities I need to use with my data

Comment: The pivotal quantity is $\bar T/\theta.$ The 'pivot' takes place at the last member of my displayed equation.

Comment: ok and if I have a chi-square with 60 df, how can I find it in the table? the table ends in 30

Comment: Get a different table, use a statistical calculator, learn to use R (if only for probability look-up), or google for chi-square tables online (of which one example is from [NIST](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda3674.htm)).)

Comment: You are correct that $\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu=k)\equiv\mathsf{Gamma}(\mathrm{shape}=k/2,\mathrm{rate}=1/2),$ so in R: `qchisq(.975,60)`
and `qgamma(.975,30,1/2)` both return $83.29767.$ Note that `qchisq` and `qgamma` are quantile functions (inverse CDFs) of chi-squared and gamma distributions, respectively.